# SerialException from existing connection while starting a new serial connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, pyserial

I have two devices connected to a raspberry Pi on ports `/dev/ttyACM0` and `/dev/ttyUSB0` respectively.

I am communicating with the `ACM0` device using a C++ serialPort instance on one program. On another program I communicate with the `USB0` device using pySerial. Both programs are running other functionality, so I will include the relevant blocks alone:

```cpp
serial::Serial serialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", 921600, serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(100));
int23_t serialPort.write(s + "\n"); //called multiple times
```

```py
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=921600)
ser.setDTR(True) # called once
```

Both are working fine individually, but when I run them together there are SerialExceptions raised by the ACM0 program such as:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'serial::SerialException' what():  SerialException device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?) failed.` (when started first)

Or

`RuntimeError: IO Exception (2): No such file or directory, file /home/ilim/catkin_ws/src/LC-CORE/serial/src/impl/unix.cc, line 151.` (when started second)

Why could this be happening?